# Java: How to display a multi-line ToolTip with AWT?

Tags: java, tooltip, awt, multiline

I wrote an application and now I'm making a tray-icon. Now I want to set a multi-line tooltiptext to the tray-icon. But I don't know how. I know how to do this with Swing:

```
component.setToolTipText("<html>Line 1<br>Line2</html>");
```

But this doesn't work with AWT. Also serarating lines by `\n` doesn't work.

I'm running on linux:

```
Ubuntu 10.04
Kernel Linux 2.6.32-22-generic
GNOME 2.30.0
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8) (6b18-1.8-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code produced a perfectly fine multi line tooltip for me:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class AWTScratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        TrayIcon ti = new TrayIcon(im, "Multiline\nmulti");
        ti.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        ti.setImageAutoSize(true);
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()){
            SystemTray st=SystemTray.getSystemTray();
            try {
                st.add(ti);
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe its a platform issue. Could you give us your OS and jvm version? Seems to be a bug, see inside [suns bug database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6580959).

Comment: Doesn't work by me. Everything in one line.

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

Answer (score 0):

`JToolTip` derives from `JComponent`, but you can simulate the effect yourself using `Graphics`-only methods, as shown in the `AlphaView` class of this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite).